# IMPORTRANGE в ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть ли возможность ARRAYFORMULA "заставить" IMPORTRANGE тянуть однотипный диапазон из раных таблиц? Что-то вроде:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({IMPORTRANGE(B1:B6,"Sheet!B10:B41")})`
где B1:B6 - диапазон адресов таблиц?

Comment: *B1:B6* - тексты. Преобразовать в ссылки - `INDIRECT`А вообще, пример надо показывать

Comment: Ячуйка в диапазоне имеет вид: 
`1KbMgOMRAvEk49urXGTOg4ainEPtjoHsvVfwsj0j`

Берет только первую.

Comment: Это не пример. Пример - небольшая демонстрация в таблицах, где можно проверить версии